# WSGI Authentication: Homegrown, Authkit, OpenID...?

Tags: python, authentication, wsgi

I want basic authentication for a very minimal site, all I personally need is a single superuser. While hard-coding a password and username in one of my source files is awfully tempting, especially since I'm hosting the site on my own server, I feel I'm breaking the law of the internets and I should just use a database (I'm using sqlite for blog posts and such). Which would be the ***easiest*** to setup, in terms of time and effort, out of OpenID or AuthKit (repoze just scares me.. it feels like too much overhead for what I'm trying to achieve), or should I roll my own?

Why I brought up OpenID is, it might just solve my spam problem (I'm currently using Akismet), to just require all commentors to login with an OpenID. I have absolutely no idea how to go about integrating OpenID with my WSGI application though (it's probably dead simple, I've never actually looked into it yet).

Answer (score 4):

also look at repose.who

http://static.repoze.org/whodocs/

Answer (score 2):

AuthKit includes a built-in OpenID module, if that helps.

The AuthKit cookbook includes a simple example here... http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/authkitcookbook/OpenID+Passurl

That said, if you only need a single login (so there's no complex user management going on), why not use Apache's built-in authentication features ([AuthUserFile .htpasswd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth.html#authuserfile) together with [Require valid-user](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#require))?

Comment: Authkit is no longer maintained. repoze.who & repoze.what are a better solution IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Opid is a very small and simple to use WSGI OpenID app: [python-opid](http://code.google.com/p/python-opid/)

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this.

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/302378/

Or, better, adapt this.

http://devel.almad.net/trac/django-http-digest/

This is quite nice.